# Enable groupbox only when checkbox is checked - pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, events, grouping

I have a groupbox which is always enable. I want it to be enable only when user want to edit something, so I made a checkbox for it. However, I have no idea how to 'link' if checkbox if selected with groupbox switching on. I want groupbox to be greyed out when disable.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [PyQt signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). There are plenty of tutorials, see for example [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_signals_and_slots.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QGroupBox, QCheckBox, QDialog, QHBoxLayout
d = QDialog()
gb = QGroupBox("Groupbox")
gb.setEnabled(False)
cb = QCheckBox("Set active")
l = QHBoxLayout(d)
l.addWidget(gb)
l.addWidget(cb)

cb.stateChanged.connect(toggleGroupBox)

def toggleGroupBox(state):
    if state > 0:
        gb.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        gb.setEnabled(False)
```

This connects a function which toggles the Groupbox to the signal which is emitted by the checkbox whenever it gets clicked.